# Solving nonlinear wave equation in a dispersive infinite waveguide

Tags: fluid-dynamics, nonlinear-equations, wave-propagation

I would like to solve a three-dimensional nonlinear wave equation in an infinite cylindrical waveguide numerically. Since the waveguide is dispersive, shocks are less likely to form. Both the convective and the materila nonlinearity (from the state equation) are considered. Is there any open source CFD codes/softwares (like CLAWPACK) to assist me with this task? Also, please help with identifying appropriate schemes.